# Hangfire - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to do some recurring jobs, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Hangfire.JobActivator.ActivateJob(Type jobType)
   at Hangfire.JobActivator.SimpleJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

I have initialized my Hangfire in my AppBuilder:

```
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationKeys.DbDefaultConnectionName].ConnectionString);

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
```

Basically, in my application you can create contracts. Everytime a contract is created, I am adding a new recurring job, using the following line:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => AutomaticMovementsCreation(contractToCreate.DebitValue, contractId, descriptionId.Result), Cron.Minutely);
```

This is the construtor of the class where the RecurringJob is being added:

```
public ContractServiceImpl(IAuthService authService, IContractStore contractStore)
{
    _contractStore = contractStore;
    _authService = authService;
}
```

The `_contractStore` is being used by the method `AutomaticMovementsCreation`.

I think it is something due to dependy injection, but I really do not know what is exacly and how to solve it. By the way I am using an Unity Container to register my application dependencies.

The whole Startup:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

    ConfigureUnity(app, httpConfiguration);
    ConfigureWebApi(httpConfiguration);
    ConfigureAuth(app);

    //Set configuration into Owin
    app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);

    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationKeys.DbDefaultConnectionName].ConnectionString);

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();

}

public void ConfigureUnity(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config) {
    UnityContainer container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer() as UnityContainer;

    if (app.GetDataProtectionProvider() == null) {
        app.UseAesDataProtectionProvider();
    }

    IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

    container.RegisterInstance(dataProtectionProvider);


    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() =>
        UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager‌​>()
    );

    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

}
```

In this method `GetConfiguredContainer` is where I register my services and datastores.

Comment: Are you using the Unity Job Activator?

Comment: in your last line config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()), you should replace the parameter with "container"

Comment: also in CreatePerOwinContext. Return container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>. Try to use the same container instance everywhere

Comment: @Amy using UnityJobActivator solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this using the following code:

```
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new ContainerJobActivator(container));
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationKeys.DbDefaultConnectionName].ConnectionString);
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();




 public class ContainerJobActivator : JobActivator
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;

        public ContainerJobActivator(UnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
        {
            return _container.Resolve(type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create an instance of the UnityContainer (at startup), load configuration from web.config, and finally associated the container with your HttpConfiguration.

I Dont remember the code exaxtly, but it goes like this:

```
var container = new UnityContainer(); 
container.LoadConfiguration(); 
config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
app.UseWebApi(config);   // Something like that
```

Comment: I have it done. I will add the whole startup to my topic.

Comment: Then you're probably missing a type mapping in your container and Unity tries to instantiate the concrete type using its public parameter-less constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the dependencies to get this working.
Install nuget unity package :

```
Install-Package Hangfire.Unity
```

And then register on Global.asax you will have BootStraper initialise method.Navigate to boot strapper class and in initialise  have following  code,

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Complete code will look something like following if you are using Unity.

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
     }



 private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
 {
    var container = new UnityContainer();       
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseUnityActivator(container);
    RegisterTypes(container);
    return container;
 }
```